# Why does my wmctrl -a command not raise my minimized Rhythmbox window?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, rhythmbox, wmctrl

#### The problem

I am currently adding a few custom shortcuts.

I fail at revealing a minimized Rhythmbox window. I use wmctrl in a shell script, see below, for this task. When I press the key combo, nothing happens (visually). Revealing Firefox, for example, using an adapted version of the shell script below works without any problems; why doesn't Rhythmbox behave the same?

*Said shell script:*

```
sh -c "if pgrep -x rhythmbox > /dev/null; then wmctrl -a rhythmbox; else rhythmbox; fi"
```

---

*Important edit:*

Apparently my script works now - without having changed anything about it. However, I ran `killall rhythmbox`. After that my shell script worked as expected. I think by just adding the fix instead of deleting the question, I maybe can help someone stumbling across the same problem. If you think you know why this happened, feel very free to share your theroy.

*Yet another edit:*

Wow, okay... Literally seconds after adding that last edit, I tried to use said shortcut again and it didn't work. I killed the process and everything worked again - the `then` AND the `else` body. After clicking in and out of a few other windows, it stopped working again. After I ran `killall rhythmbox` and seeing it work again perfectly, even after I had failed to reproduce the error, I came to the conclusion that it's acting kind of random. Well, pseudorandom, of course. If you want to try it for yourself, you know how to do it. You can get wmctrl by running `sudo apt install wmctrl`. I am using version 1.07 of it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and very confused.

*Last edit (never say last):*

I actually got Firefox to reveal itself now upon pressing the key combination. That's cool, just not what I want. I will drink a big cup of coffee now and do something else, wow.

Comment: Hi Reum, posted my answer.l Please mention if all is clear (or not).

Comment: @JacobVlijm All clear, however I found one little error, I think. See your answers comments.

Comment: Hi Reum, see my comment on the answer. The fun part is this way that you can use one script for multiple applications, if you make the application an argument to the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The issue: rhythmbox is changing the window name

The issue is that you are identifying the window by its *name*, using `wmctrl -a`. From `man wmctrl`:

```
-a <WIN>
    Switch to the desktop containing the window <WIN>, raise the window, and give it focus.
```

`<WIN>` is an identifying *string* in the window name.

Especially in your case, this is likely to cause errors, since Rhythmbox changes the window name, depending on the song. You need to identify the window by either its window *class* or its `id`

The latter can be done using:

```
wmctrl -ia
```

where the option `-i` stands for window-id:

```
   -i     Interpret window arguments (<WIN>) as  a  numeric  value  rather
          than  a  string name for the window. If the numeric value starts
          with the prefix '0x' it is assumed to be a hexadecimal number.
```

Both the window-id and the pid a window belongs to can be retrieved from the window-list, called by the command:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

---

A reliable command to raise the most recent window from e.g. Rhythmbox then is:

```
wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep rhythmbox)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

#### Explanation:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

lists all windows, including their pids. An important property of the command is that it lists the windows ***in the order they were created***. 
Therefore:

```
wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep rhythmbox)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

will:

- list all windows + pids they belong to:

  ```
  wmctrl -lp
  ```
- find the ones ones belonging to rhythmbox:

  ```
  grep "$(pgrep rhythmbox)"
  ```
- find the last one (which is also the last created one):

  ```
  tail -1
  ```
- extract the first string in the line (which is the window -id):

  ```
  awk '{ print $1 }'
  ```

The command:

```
wmctrl -ia
```

will then raise the most recent Rhythmbox window by its id.

#### Script

For convenience reasons, and to prevent issues with quotes, I'd make a tiny script of it with the command, and run it from a shortcut:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep rhythmbox)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

Make it ***executable*** and Add shortut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```bsh
/path/to/script.sh
```

#### Additionally

It looks like you are using the command/script for multiple applications. Instead of making separate scripts for each and every application, you can make the application *argument* to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
app=$(pgrep $1)
wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$app" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

Then

```
 /path/to/script.sh gedit
```

will raise the most recently created `gedit` window, while

```
/path/to/script.sh rhythmbox
```

will raise the most recently created `rhythmbox` window, and so on.

Comment: This worked great! However, I only got it to work with an "external" script and calling it. If you paste your given line in the command section, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Reum12 That is correct, since the rules for shortcuts are the same as using a .desktop file. In case of complicated commands, it is not the same as running commands in terminal :)

Comment: Cool, I will definetly use only one script from now on. I wasn't before, heh. `if pgrep rhythmbox > /dev/null; then wmctrl -ia $(wmctrl -lp | grep $(pgrep rhythmbox) | tail -1 | awk "{ print $1 }"); else rhythmbox; fi` is what I ended up using, checking if Rhythmbox is running and if not, starting it. Works a treat, thanks a lot! I removed all unnecessary `"` and `'`s. I am very new to shell scripting, please let me know if there is a reason you used them!

Comment: @Reum12 see: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html very well possible that it works without, but for better practice...

Comment: Added them back in :)